# Developing a finite difference scheme for non-linear conservation law

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations, viscosity-solutions

When considering equations of the form $$u_t + f(u)_x = 0, $$
there are many finite difference schemes that will converge to smooth solutions, such as the one based on Lax-Friedrichs, 
$$\frac{u_{j}^{n+1} - \frac{1}{2}(u_{j+1}^n + u_{j-1}^n)}{k} + \frac{f(u_{j+1}^n)-f(u_{j-1}^n)}{2h} = 0.$$
This scheme in particular is consistent, TV-stable, and the flux function $$F(v,w) = \frac{\lambda}{2}(w-v) + \frac{1}{2}(f(v)+f(w)) $$
is Lipschitz, so the numerical solution will converge to the weak solution as $h, k \to 0$. However, I believe schemes like these may converge to weak solutions that violate the entropy condition, or are only valid for a finite time $T$. Does there exist a generalization to these methods that converge for all $t > 0$? I would imagine we could consider schemes involving an artificial viscosity term $\epsilon u_{xx}$, since we would expect smooth solutions for $t >0$, and take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ to get our desired approximation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Courant-Friedrichs-Lewy condition, the Lax-Friedrichs method converges to the vanishing viscosity solution by construction. It is one of the most robust methods, and will provide entropy solutions.

Even if that isn't a proof of the result you are looking for, let's look for the scheme's *modified equation* (see e.g. literature references by R.J. LeVeque). Using Taylor series, one shows that for smooth solutions
\begin{aligned}
\frac{u_j^{n+1} - \frac12( u_{j+1}^n + u_{j-1}^n )}{k} &= (u_t)_j^n + \frac{k}{2}(u_{tt})_j^n - \frac{h^2}{2k} (u_{xx})_j^n + O(h^2, k^2)
\\
\frac{f(u_{j+1}^{n}) - f(u_{j-1}^n)}{2h} &= [f(u)_x]_j^n + O(h^2) .
\end{aligned}
Up to higher-order terms (h.o.), we therefore have $u_t + f(u)_x = \frac{h}{2\lambda} (u_{xx} - \lambda^2 u_{tt})$ with $\lambda = k/h$.
Then, the PDE produces
\begin{aligned}
u_{tx} &= -f(u)_{xx} = -f'(u) u_{xx} \\
u_{tt} &= -f(u)_{xt} = -f'(u)u_{xt},
\end{aligned}
which leads to the scheme's modified equation
$$
u_t + f(u)_x = \frac{h}{2\lambda}\left(1 - \lambda^2 f'(u)^2\right) u_{xx} + \text{h.o.}
$$
Note the vanishing diffusion term in the r.h.s.